# How to get IP from "http://" or "www" in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

How do I get something in PHP/Curl to grab the IP of the URL for me? It's going to be a simple interface that fetches URL IP's back for me.

E.g. Enter "http://mysite.com" then I hit submit then I should get the IP of the mysite.com back.

Comment: Regarding the second part, the *“simple interface linking”*, that is basic html form interaction, you learn in every single php tutorial…

Comment: What is *simple interface linking* ?

Answer (score 14):

[`gethostbyname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php)

```
$ip_string = gethostbyname( "stackoverflow.com" );
echo $ip_string; //returns ip address, ie 12.34.56.78
```

Comment: What about the simple interface linking? E.g. submit, enter ip.

Comment: The function is limited to resolving IPv4 AFAIK.

Comment: This was not an answer to your original comment... It was a comment on `gethostbyname()`. See http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49493.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [`gethostbyname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) function.

Comment: What about the simple interface linking? E.g. submit, enter ip.

Comment: @Raymond: what about doing yourself?

Comment: Zerkms ... +1 for late night amusement !